# is there a way to write documentation in a mysql table?

Tags: mysql, documentation

There are some attributes that is not fully clear what they do or how they are calculated. Both DBA's who don't need to know about application and developers access this. Is there a way to save something like for example in the information_schema that would then be accessible like:

```
 select information_schema.db_name.table_name.description from tables 

 or could be aliased like:

 select x.description from users
```

Or other ideas on how to handle?

Comment: What, there is no proper *external* documentation about the design/model? :(

Comment: `A comment for a column can be specified with the COMMENT option, up to 255 characters long. The comment is displayed by the SHOW CREATE TABLE and SHOW FULL COLUMNS statements.`

Comment: there is docs but more for comments on how things work - a 255 char would probably work. Would be nice if were a little longer. the syntax for updating a comment looks painful....   honestly, would want it to be like a commenting system or github system that could be accessed within either ide or command line like "What does x do?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COMMENT` table attribute:

1) upon creation:

```
CREATE TABLE `FormData` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `FormId` varchar(20) collate utf8_czech_ci default NULL,
  `Content` text collate utf8_czech_ci,
) ENGINE=InnoDB COMMENT='Stored data from general form'
```

2) at any time

```
alter table `FormData` comment='Any other comments'
```

Unfortunately the table comment can be only [up to 60 characters long](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).